# VBA code to select the first shape in the current active paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2013, I need a simple VBA code in my macro which selects the first shape that exists in the current active paragraph.

Note: the shape that I need the code to select is a custom shape that I have created and saved as an autotext in BuildingBlockEntries.  The code I use to insert my shape is :

```
Application.Templates( _
 "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm") _
 .BuildingBlockEntries("_red_box").insert where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

The purpose of selecting the shape is to paste clipboard contents into it via the following code:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste)
```

I am new to VBA.  What would be the VBA code to select the shape?

Answer (score 1):

My VBA is a bit rusty, but if you insert with the same name, and give it an index property, you can use item(0) to select the first, item(1) to select the second, etc... where item() is the name of your instance, and 0,1,2,3... is which item it is.

It may be as simple as adding:

```
dim MyShapes
MyShapes(0) = Application.Templates( ... )
```

Edit by john.s2011:

```
Sub Mymacro() 
    Dim MyShapes 
    MyShapes(0) = Application.Templates( _ 
    "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm") _
    .Buildi‌​ngBlockEntries("myshape").insert where:=Selection.Range, _
    RichText:=True 

    Dim Rng As Range 
    With ActiveDocument 
        Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\para") 
        Rng.ShapeRange(0).Select Rng.Paste 
    End With 
end sub
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for reply. sorry what should i add at the above code so that it assigns an index to my shape when it is being inserted?  really new to VBA

Comment: I wrote that in my code.

Comment: may you amend it:                                                                                                                                                                          Sub Mymacro()
         
   Dim MyShapes
      MyShapes(0)= Application.Templates( _
 "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm").BuildingBlockEntries("myshape").insert where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
   Dim Rng As Range
       With ActiveDocument
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\para")
    Rng.ShapeRange(0).Select
    Rng.Paste
    End With
end sub

Comment: @john.s2011 added it to the post. Tnx.